# ajax doesn't show any response to a list of json objects, as rest api response

Tags: json, ajax, spring, rest

I use Spring for running my rest API service, i cant get the list of json object that my service send from a sample html file and plz tell me how can i access to the first object.

this is the sample output of my rest API service:

```
[{"src_ip":"1.1.1.1","src_id":"98","date":1470527874000},
{"src_ip":"1.1.2.1","src_id":"25","date":1470527934000},
{"src_ip":"1.1.2.1","src_id":"25","date":1470527934000}]
```

and this the code that i used in my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing Results</title>
<!--TODO badan version e CDN e jquery use shavad-->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/restapi2",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.List').append(data);
       $('.data').append(data[0]);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br><br>
        <p class="List"></p>
        <br><br>
        <p class="data"></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I should say that when i run the sample of this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/) on my html file, it worked Properly.

> Updated part:

after fixing last error,still I didn't get any correct data to show in my browser, but this time, the console get something but i don't know how to use them. this is a snapshot of it and the left side show that two object were sent.

[image]

and this content of that object:

[image]

Comment: Is your Spring application returns the data ? Are you getting data when you just enter the url in browser/ or any other tools like POSTMAN ?

Comment: i don't try it on postman, but when i checkout "http://localhost:8080/restapi2" i see my response.

Comment: postman getted response too.

Comment: Then just open the developer console of your browser and put a break point at $('.List').append(data); and check the result

Comment: there was a err telling this: **getting my rest.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/restapi2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: Are you running your javascript in the same machine or different machine ?

Comment: both are same, as i mentioned i run a spring web service for creating rest response, then i created a html file in my desktop for getting that response, although when i check, the html files that i created in my project space in intellij, have the same problem.

Comment: What's the url that you are using to host this html/javascript ? (i.e How are you accessing this page from browser)? Something like http://localhost:8080/someapp/ ?

Comment: yes, I use http://localhost:8080/restapi2

Comment: Is it resolved now ?

Comment: not yet, i add **@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")** in my appContoller.java for allowing CORs in server side but i still couldn't find a way for make it work on client *.html side ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion on the comment the reason is you were trying to access the different domain than your page which is prohibited by browsers as a security precaution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/restapi2"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.List').append(data);
       $('.data').append(data[0].);
    });
});
```

["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: I update my code, for getting rid of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" but again i didn`t get any output.

Comment: can you help me with this part again, I really cant figure out what's the reason of this problem?

Comment: If both(your html page and your service) are in same domain you don't need to do any configuration for 'No Access Control origin'. Make sure both are correct, there may be typos as well